# How to add the current title to the breadcrumb without preprocess function?

Tags: theming, 8, hooks, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to get the title into my breadcrumb path without using a preprocess function. [Drupal 8 Add the current title to the breadcrumb](http://www.thenoccave.com/2015/01/08/drupal-8-add-the-current-title-to-the-breadcrumb/) shows how to do it with preprocess function which is not what I'm trying to do.

I want my output be like this:

[image]

Here is what have been trying and have not work yet.

**breadcrumb.html.twig**

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a breadcrumb trail.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - breadcrumb: Breadcrumb trail items.
 */
#}
{% if breadcrumb %}
    <nav class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
        <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Breadcrumb'|t }}</h2>
        <ol>{{ 'You are here:'|t }}
            {% for item in breadcrumb %}
                <li>
                    {% if item.url %}

                        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ item.text }}
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
                {{ '>'|t }} {{title}}
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

For some reason the title is not been display when I use `{{ title }}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Why is my title not being displayed on my breadcrumb title?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's bad practice to use preprocess in D8, I think it would be more accurate and reasonable to say something like: "Adding classes to your markup via preprocess functions in D8 is discouraged." As the others are saying, if you need a variable that's not in the template then you likely need to add a preprocess to create/populate that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what I will need to use preprocess function because `{{title}}` was not part of the **breadcrumb.html.twig**. I ended up doing this to achieve this my output:

**mytheme.theme**

```
<?php

function mytheme_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables){

        if(($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $variables['breadcrumb']){
    // Adding the a divider of between home an the title of the page.
            $variables['breadcrumb'][] = array(
                'text' => '>'
            );
    // Adding the title of the page in the breadcrumb
            $variables['breadcrumb'][] = array(
                'text' => $node->getTitle(),
                'url' => $node->URL()
            );

        }
    }
```

**breadcrumb.html.twig**

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a breadcrumb trail.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - breadcrumb: Breadcrumb trail items.
 */
#}
{% if breadcrumb %}
    <nav class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
        <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Breadcrumb'|t }}</h2>
        {{ 'You are here:'|t }}
        <div class="breadcrumb">
            {% for item in breadcrumb %}
                <span>
                    {% if item.url %}
                            <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ item.text }}
                    {% endif %}
                </span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

For more information about my solving this issue you can visit - [Light Skeleton - Breadcrumb D8 Port](https://www.drupal.org/node/2608902)

Comment: This method only adds node title to breadcrumb. If i want to add all page title to breadcrumb, then how can do this?

Comment: darol100 - it is for nodes solution only. What about another types of pages?

Answer (score 8):

There is also an alter hook for breadcrumbs, where you can alter them in a non-theme specific way, in case the breadcrumbs are also used somewhere else.

I've implemented this in a project:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_system_breadcrumb_alter(array &$breadcrumb, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
  // Append the current page title to the breadcrumb for non-admin routes.
  if ($breadcrumb && !\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) {

    $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')
      ->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());
    if (!empty($title)) {
      breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($title, '<none>'));
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT for Drupal 8.2.x

I add a lot of error with this code, which I believe is the best approach for altering the breadcrumb has seen on [Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_system_breadcrumb_alter/8.2.x).
So here is the code for Drupal 8.2.x

```
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_system_breadcrumb_alter(\Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb, \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
  // Append the current page title to the breadcrumb for non-admin routes.
  if ($breadcrumb && !\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) {

    $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle(\Drupal::request(), $route_match->getRouteObject());
    if (!empty($title)) {
      $breadcrumb->addLink(\Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute($title, '<none>'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice implementation but I just want to point out to others that it will only work in a module, not a theme. See @cmsbots.com answer for one that works in a theme.

Comment: Well lets comment, my edit was rejected by reviewers... There is 2 main concerns about this code, after Drupal 8.0 release `&$breadcrumb` is a Object not an array, to correct, change to `Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb` and `$request` variable is not defined in code, change to `\Drupal::request()`. Minor mistake `breadcrumb->addLink...` misspell `$`. Just for future reference, like pointed by Mark, this is not exactly what OP asks for, but there is more up votes than correct answer...

Comment: since 8.4.x (https://www.drupal.org/node/2891075) you would need to add $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['url.path']); to the code, otherwise you will run into caching issues, for example if you have multiple menu items with same parent.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the variable {{title}} will not avaliable to breadcrumb.html.twig. You have to to use HOOK_preprocess_breadcrumb in your .theme file.

P.S: In D8, it is bad practice only if you try to display the data from preprocesser function. It is nothing wrong of you try to add extra variable in preprocesser. Here more clarification https://www.drupal.org/node/1920746

In YOUYTHEME.theme file

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $page_title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());

  //this variable will avaliable in twig file. 
  $variables['breadcrumb'][] = array(
    'text' => $page_title
  );
}
```

Comment: Any example on how I can pass the {{title}}?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the suggested solutions may have troubles with cache because the logic happens in the preprocess (`YOURTHEME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables)`). I would recommend using some contrib modules or implement their solutions:

[Easy breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb): Replaces core breadcrumbs with configurable breadcrumbs that follow Breadcrumb best-practices.

[Current page crumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/current_page_crumb): Extends the Drupal 8 core system breadcrumbs to append the current page title as a text only breadcrumb.

Comment: this can be avoided using `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';`, see: https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/drupal-8-quick-handbook-on-cache-api

Answer (score 2):

There is a new module called [Current Page Crumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/current_page_crumb) that can help you.

> Current Page Crumb extends the Drupal 8 core system breadcrumbs to
>   append the current page title as a text only breadcrumb. Admin paths
>   are left unmodified. The module has no configuration.

And the author has made a [blog post](http://www.gregboggs.com/drupal8-breadcrumbs/) talking about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocess function for breadcrumbs in core is:

```
function template_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $variables['breadcrumb'] = array();
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Link $link */
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $key => $link) {
    $variables['breadcrumb'][$key] = array('text' => $link->getText(), 'url' => $link->getUrl()->toString());
  }
}
```

It only provides the breadcrumbs, nothing else. So if you want to use other variables, you have to put them into the variables array in your own preprocess function.

Comment: Any example on how I can pass the {{title}}?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, use below code in your custom module or create a new custom module.
I assume you already have understanding on how to create a custom module for Drupal 8/9.
Create your services file mymodule.services.yml and add below code,

```
  mymodule.breadcrumb_nodes:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Breadcrumb\MyModuleBreadcrumbBuilder
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 10001 }
```

You could set key as above like breadcrumb_nodes or breadcrumb or breadcrumb_terms etc as per your needs.
Then create breadcrumb builder file under mymodule/src/Breadcrumb/ directory named as MyModuleBreadcrumbBuilder.php and add below code

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Breadcrumb;

use Drupal;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

class MyModuleBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   *  
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // This breadcrumb will apply for all nodes.
    $parameters = $route_match->getParameters()->all();

    //Checking if node then only calling our builder otherwise loading default loader
    if (isset($parameters['node'])) {
     return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   * Add your logic in below method
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {

    $parameters = $route_match->getParameters()->all();

    $node = $parameters['node'];

    //Getting latest node revision
    $vid = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getLatestRevisionId($node->id());
    $node_new = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadRevision($vid);
    $node_array = $node_new->toArray();

    //Creating new Breadcrumb
    $breadcrumb = new \Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb();

    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));

    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($node_array["title"][0]["value"], 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $node->id()]));

    //Adding cache control,otherwise all breadcrumb will be the same for all pages.
    //By setting a "cache context" to the "url", each requested URL gets it's
    //own cache. This way a single breadcrumb isn't cached for all pages on the
    //site.
    $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(["url"]);
    $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(["node:{$node->id()}"]);

    return $breadcrumb;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks!!