# Adding a non-link element to the end of the breadcrumb

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

For example, in a "blog post" page I'd like the breadcrumb to display like this:

> [Blog](http://google.com) > [Recipes](http://google.com) > Recipe

I'm controlling all breadcrumbs from a single place, a class that implements `BreadcrumbBuilderInterface`. Its `build` method looks like this:

```
public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  $b = new Breadcrumb();

  $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');

  if ($node && $node->getType() == 'blog_post') {
    $b->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Blog'), 'blog.home'));
    $b->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Recipes'), 'blog.recipes_landing'));

    //I want this next item to not be a link, and to show "Recipe" and not the node title.
    //$b->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Recipe'), 'nothing!'));
  }

  return $b;
}
```

How can I make this happen? I saw somewhere (not sure where, in a code comment perhaps) that this last item is supposed to be added in the theme layer, but I don't want to split my logic, especially since I don't just want all breadcrumbs to show the page title as the last item (instead, for example, I want it to say "Recipe" if the content type is `blog_post`).

Comment: That's quite a bit of work I think - you'll need a custom `Breadbrumb` class (the default works with typed links only), a custom `BeadcrumbBuilder` service (the default only works with the default `Breadcrumb` class), your own theme function (The `links` theme won't work for this, especially if you're interested in getting decent markup produced), a custom block for the new breadcrumb, etc. Hope I'm wrong but I don't see an easier way

Comment: Yeah I was just working my way through all that.. it feels like it should be simpler.

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/180042/31.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do almost like in your suggestion. You just need to use `'<none>'` instead of `'nothing!'`.

```
$b->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Recipe'), '<none>'));
```

Comment: Well, that was disappointingly simple... I'll go remove a bunch of unnecessary code now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the (very) complicated solution I implemented for this.

In a custom module, extend the Breadcrumb class, like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb as Source;

class Breadcrumb extends Source {
  private $current = NULL;

  /**
   * @param string|NULL $title
   */
  public function setCurrentTitle($title) {
    $this->current = $title;
  }

  public function toRenderable() {
    $array = parent::toRenderable();
    $array['#current'] = $this->current;
    return $array;
  }

}
```

Then my `build` method from the question becomes this:

```
public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  $b = new Breadcrumb();

  $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');

  if ($node && $node->getType() == 'blog_post') {
    $b->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Blog'), 'blog.home'));
    $b->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Recipes'), 'blog.recipes_landing'));

    $b->setCurrentTitle($this->t('Recipe')); //yayhere!
  }

  return $b;
}
```

But, then, in my .theme file, I added this beautiful thing:

```
function mytheme_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['breadcrumb']['variables']['current'] = [];
}
```

And, finally, the twig file became this:

```
{% if breadcrumb %}
  <nav class="breadcrumb container" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
    <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Breadcrumb'|t }}</h2>
    <ol>
    {% for item in breadcrumb %}
      <li>
        {% if item.url %}
          <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
        {% else %}
          {{ item.text }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if current %}
      <li>{{ current }}</li>
    {% endif %}
    </ol>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

*Nice, eh?*

Comment: A side-effect I just noticed is that if there are no actual links and only a "current page", the thing won't show (because of the condition in the twig file). But I'm calling it "by design" since, on second thought, an empty label is pretty useless :)

Comment: nice! how exactly do you implement the breadcrumb class? do i have to specify that in my services? and how do i make sure my custom builder class uses the custom breadcrumb class?